# How to get focus to the treeview node with txt extension on closing or hiding subform

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Hi all i will have a form loaded when i click on datagridview cell which was my main form. Now what i need is when i click on save on the form opened i will close this form. Then i have to get the tree view node get selected automatically.

I tried by writing

```
       treeview.focus()
    treeview.select ()
```

but this does not works for me.

On my main form i will have tree view control and datagridview control.

Any idea please

After save and all of work my done i called a function which i write in main.cs

This is the code

```
  public void loadingDatafrom()
   {
    treeview.focus();
    treeview.select();
   }
```

My nodes will be as follows

```
    ACH
     |-> Some.txt
       |->Child
         |->Child1
           |->Child like this i will have and these were create programatically except root node all are created dynamically
```

Comment: give some idea about nodes of your tree

Comment: This is the exact same question that you asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845685/is-it-possible-to-get-one-of-the-child-node-get-selected-programatically. What problems are you having with the solution *you* posted there?

Comment: @ cody Gray : For that i got the solution but this is different i tried by writing that and then only posted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with Reference to **riffnl** answer

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FindNode(treeView1.Nodes, ".txt");
    this.ActiveControl = treeView1;
}  

bool found = false;
public void FindNode(TreeNodeCollection nodeCollection, string TextToFind)
{
   foreach (TreeNode node in nodeCollection)
   {
       if (found)
          continue;
       if (node.Text.Contains(TextToFind))
       {
          treeView1.SelectedNode = node;
          TreeNode parentNode = node.Parent;
          while (parentNode != null)
          {
              parentNode.Expand();
              parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
          }
          found = true;
          break;
       }
       FindNode(node.Nodes, TextToFind);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line following the one where you launch your subform (eg: secondForm.ShowDialog(); or something similar, in the line after this line), add the treeView.Focus and treeview.select statements so that when you return to the calling form, the focus is on the treeview.

Comment: Hi this ok is there any other way to get the node with txt as selected node

Comment: if you know the index number then you can give it as:  treeview.Nodes[index].focus

Answer (score 1):

This code opens the treeview (expands) with the selectednode and selects the node

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FindNode(treeView1.Nodes, ".txt");
        this.ActiveControl = treeView1;
    }
    public void FindNode(TreeNodeCollection nodeCollection, string TextToFind)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodeCollection)
        {
            if (node.Text.Contains(TextToFind))
            {
                treeView1.SelectedNode = node;
                TreeNode parentNode = node.Parent;
                while (parentNode != null)
                {
                    parentNode.Expand();
                    parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
                }
                break;
            }
            FindNode(node.Nodes, TextToFind);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.Focus();
}
```

**UPDATED:**

this will do your work but I also agree this is not efficient way

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        treeView1.ExpandAll();
        while (true)
        {
            if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Text.Contains(".txt"))
            {
                treeView1.Focus();
                return;
            }
            treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.SelectedNode.NextVisibleNode;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: I need to get focus on the node with txt extension

Comment: this will got focus back to the state you left

Comment: I need the node with .txt to be selected is it possible

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to select a particular node in your `TreeView`, whereas the code snippet that you posted above only sets focus to the `TreeView` control itself.

To do this, you need to set the [`SelectedNode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx) of the `TreeView` control to the individual node item that you want to appear as selected. The specified node is automatically scrolled into view and all of its its parent nodes are expanded so that it is visible. For example:

```
myTreeView.SelectedNode = myTreeView.Nodes[0]; //where 0 is the index of the node you want to select
```

You commented on another answer that you're trying to find the node with the "txt" extension, which suggests that you don't necessarily know the index or location of the node that you want to select in the `TreeView`. To find it, you'll have to loop through all of the nodes in the [`TreeView.Nodes` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodes.aspx) and look for a match. Once you've found a node matching your criteria, you can set that node item as the selected node:

```
foreach (TreeNode node in myTreeView.Nodes)
{
    if (node.Text.Contains("txt")) //or however you want to find a matching node
    {
        myTreeView.SelectedNode = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: What ever i did only the root node is getting selected

Comment: You're probably selecting the root node because it is the node with an index of 0. (The first node displayed in the control always has an index of 0.) Also note that each `TreeNode` contains its own `Nodes` collection, so if you have multiple levels of nodes in your treeview, you'll need to loop through *each level* to find the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void FindNode(TreeNodeCollection nodeCollection)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodeCollection)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode nd in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (nd.Text.Contains(".txt"))
                {
                    nd.Select(); 
                    return;
                }
            }
        }  
    }
```