# Is it possible to select leaf tree node programatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am working on TreeView with checkbox(Parent and leaf) where I have to make some leaf nodes selected programatically.

Is it possible ?

I tried forach loop on treeview node but can make selected(checkbox) particular node.

I tried following solution 
[Is it possible to get one of the child node get selected programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845685/is-it-possible-to-get-one-of-the-child-node-get-selected-programatically)

but I am getting error on `SelectedNode` that its read only

Code is as below :

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="Leaf">
</asp:TreeView>
```

Now I am adding treeview node

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ModuleName"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Id"].ToString()));

   DataRow[] result = ds.Tables[1].Select("ModuleId = '"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Id"].ToString()+"'");
                    foreach (DataRow row in result)
                    {
                        TreeView1.Nodes[i].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(row["PageCode"].ToString(), row["Id"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
```

and Now how do make particular leaf node selected ??

Answer (score 1):

Please add you code so we can understand and answer proper.

If no **TreeNode** is currently selected, the **SelectedNode** property is null.